# Detect Input IDLE on MacOS and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

It's need to port our software on MacOS and Linux. How can I detect input IDLE on MacOS and Linux using Delphi 10.2?

In Windows I use :

```
 aLastInputInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TLastInputInfo);
 GetLastInputInfo(aLastInputInfo);

 case (GetTickCount - aLastInputInfo.dwTime) / 1000 / 60 > IDLE_TIMER of
   True: Synchronize(OnExecuted); 
   False: Synchronize(OnExcepted); 
 end;
```

But this is platform specific, relying on Windows API calls.

Comment: Have you checked how others do it? Most of the time it's quite easy to translate. Perhaps start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418210/notification-when-the-system-is-idle-or-not-on-os-x

Comment: What do you mean when you say "System IDLE"?  Show us what you are checking on Windows so we can understand what you mean.

Comment: For Windows I use this code:

aLastInputInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TLastInputInfo);
GetLastInputInfo(aLastInputInfo);case (GetTickCount - aLastInputInfo.dwTime) / 1000 / 60 > IDLE_TIMER of
      True:   Synchronize(OnExecuted);
      False:  Synchronize(OnExcepted);
end;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418210/notification-when-the-system-is-idle-or-not-on-os-xI 

I saw this link, but I do not know how to use it in Delphi

Comment: Much better, I've edited your question.