# Detect global key events

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I detect global key events without using addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask. I need only the notification that a key was pressed, do not need to know which key exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could poll `CGEventSourceSecondsSinceLastEventType` for the time since the last keyboard event.  I don't know of any way to be notified of a key event without finding out what key was pressed.  A Quartz event tap would have the same security restrictions as `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`, which I'm guessing is why you want to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I have actually found what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643579/objective-c-get-notifications-about-a-users-idle-state .